# issues with Searching in Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode6

I am using this piece of code to find the existance of data. But i am getting this error that Use of Undeclared Identifier "`appDelegate`".

```
- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender {
CoreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate =
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context =
   [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc =
   [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts"
   inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred =
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name = %@)",
    _name.text];
[request setPredicate:pred];
NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
    error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) {
   _status.text = @"No matches";
} else {
   matches = objects[0];
   _address.text = [matches valueForKey:@"address"];
   _phone.text = [matches valueForKey:@"phone"];
   _status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
       @"%lu matches found", (unsigned long)[objects count]];
}
}
```

I have included the `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` .Will I have to include some other file. When i save data it works fine.

Comment: import CoreDataAppDelegate file

Comment: where i can find the CoreDataAppDelegate file @Arunakumari

Comment: your app delegate file  @rahul

Comment: @Arunakumari how can i delete some text from entity as if i want to replace search to delete\

Comment: you want delete the text from  entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have imported the app delegate header

```
#import "CoreDataAppDelegate.h"
```

Try casting the AppDelegate as `CoreDataAppDeleage`

```
CoreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CoreDataAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: how can i delete some text from entity as if i want to replace search to delete\ – @Adam

Answer (score 0):

```
CoreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate =
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Replace above line to below line

```
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 0):

For deleting text based on Id

```
#pragma mark - delete tracking details

- (void)deleteTrackingId:(NSString *)trackingId

    {
        appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        NSError *error;

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entityOne = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrackingList" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entityOne];
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trackingId == %@",trackingId];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Could not delete Entity Objects");
        }

        for (TrackingList *trackingObject in fetchedObjects) {
            [managedObjectContext deleteObject:trackingObject];
        }

        [appDelegate saveContext];
    }
```

Comment: suppose i have a row of three column name age salary . If I pass name in tracking ID will it delete entire row or just the name @Arunakumari

Comment: if tracking id is 1 means that related info deleted .tracking id is primarykey.so based on primary key i had delete the deletails.

Comment: can we discuss it in chat room  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71170/ios-magicians @Arunakumari

Comment: or you want delete the details based on salary column provide that column instead of trackingId